# FancyBox на Iphone 5

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

Использую движок WordPress, с помощью модуля FancyBox отображаю всплывающее окно.
На IPhone 5 при попытке ввести данные в поле ввода, окно просто уезжает, хотя должно быть в центре. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть? 
[image: Скрин]

Comment: хоть бы ссылку на сайт приложили бы

Comment: consulting-uslugi.tmweb.ru

Comment: у меня нормально всё отображается